# emulator errors for hpet and create sensors port

Tags: android, centos

I got 1 emulator error from the latest Andriod SDK(on both Ubuntu11.10 and CentOS6.2):

> [@localhost ~]$/android-sdks/tools/emulator -avd api15&
>   emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Connection refused

On CentOS6.2, there is also an HPET error.(even though my HPET was set to 1024 already):

> [@localhost ~]$ cat /proc/sys/dev/hpet/max-user-freq
>   1024
>   [@localhost ~]$/android-sdks/tools/emulator -avd api15&
>   Could not configure '/dev/hpet' to have a 1024Hz timer. This is not a fatal error, but for better emulation accuracy type: 'echo 1024 > /proc/sys/dev/hpet/max-user-freq' as root.
>   emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Connection refused

I am at my wits end. What is it trying to tell me? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here are the background info:

> [@localhost ~]$ emulator -version
>   Android emulator version 16.0 (build_id ICS_MR0-234950)
>   Copyright (C) 2006-2011 The Android Open Source Project and many others.
>   This program is a derivative of the QEMU CPU emulator (www.qemu.org).
>   ...
>
> [@localhost ~]cat /etc/issue.net
>   CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
>   Kernel \r on an \m
>
> [@localhost ~]uname -a
>   Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 24 02:13:44 GMT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: the hpet error message went away after emulator upgrade. Thanks Andriod team!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is not a real problem. In the emulator you do not have sensors that's why there is an error here. This a common error for all emulators for all versions.

As for the second case I've never noticed such error.